# RegEx - Why does group 1 have all the characters?

Tags: regex

RegEx: `(^.*?)\s+(.*)`

Search Text: `Director ANURADHA GUPTA`

Replace: `$1 - $2`

I am expecting: `Director - ANURADHA GUPTA`

But instead I get: `Director ANURADHA GUPTA - Director`

I would like to split the first word into the first group and the second words onwards into another group.

UPDATE:

Sorry for the confusion guys. I am using java reg ex:. Here's a Groovy script that explains what I am trying to do

```
   import java.util.regex.Pattern    

def pattern = Pattern.compile("(^.*?)\\s(.*)");
def matcher = pattern.matcher("Director ANURADHA GUPTA");
if(matcher.matches()){
    println matcher.group(1);
    println matcher.group(2);

}

Output
Director
ANURADHA GUPTA
```

This works! I was trying to test against the reg ex tester chrome plugin:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regexp-tester-app/cmmblmkfaijaadfjapjddbeaoffeccib?hl=en

Assuming that if it works there it should work in java as well. Its on that plugin that things didn't work.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Also, does `$3` output anything, by any chance?

Comment: I tested it [here](http://regex101.com/r/dA3aX4) and everything is working fine.

Comment: you probably need to replace with `$2 - $3`. $1 probably always stores the entire match.

Comment: specify the language/tool you are using..regex implementation differs across languages/tools..Also specify the complete text you are searching..

Comment: You would get that result if you enclosed your entire regex with parentheses. Please show the *code* that produces the result you're seeing (you know, a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable) Example](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: As Anirudh mentioned please specify the language/tool so we could help more as it seems to be not a great problem.

Comment: @OGHaza: There is no regex flavor that works the way you describe.  I think Tim has the right idea, that the OP has wrapped the whole regex in a capturing group without thinking about it.  I see that pretty often.

Comment: @AlanMoore, fair enough, I don't know every regex flavour so I incorrectly assumed

Answer (score 1):

More efficient would be replace `\s+` with `" - "`.

See demo **[here](http://regex101.com/r/wD3xW6)**.

Comment: I don't think so that it will catch anything as the mentioned string input is: `Director ANURADHA GUPTA`?

Comment: theres no `' - '` in his input string

Comment: @Tafari - You are wrong. Did you check demo link in my answer?

Comment: @OGHaza - Read again. It is replacing string, why it should be in input string?

Comment: Ah I do see what you mean, I thought you meant replace in his regex.

Comment: @Ωmega First I didn't downvote you. Someone went downvote flurry on all answers it seems... You have said replace `\s+` which only appears in the regex pattern mentioned by the question owner. And when u use the regex with ` - ` instead of `\s+` it will find nothing in the string `Director ANURADHA GUPTA`. As he doesn't replace anything he just wants to add ` - ` between two capture groups.

Comment: @Tafari - Again: Did you check demo link in my answer?

Comment: @Ωmega yes I know it is possible to replace it like that and it would be the best solution here, yet the person asking here is using another approach.

Comment: @Tafari - I would not call it another approach. Replacing second group `(.*)` with `$2` is actually no replacing, just waste of resources with no change.

Comment: The other answers deserve their downvotes because they both expect `$1` and `$2` to represent the first and second capturing groups as they appear in the OP's regex.  They don't, because the OP is doing something wrong in code he's not showing us.  There's nothing we can do about that, but this answer at least solves *the original problem* by avoiding the use of capturing groups entirely. +1

Answer (score -1):

Another way to ensure you are splitting with only one word in the first group is this:

`^(\w+)` replaced with `$1 -`

The original problem must have been that you had parens around the whole regex, which became the first capture group.